# A proper way to filter for a status when the status is explicitly filtered out with a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query that is explicitly looking for "active" items (108) and filtering out "inactive" items (117).

Although, I have found that when I try to run this query and search for inactive items, of course, nothing comes back because we have stated `WHERE  COALESCE(i.item_status_id, 108) <> 117`

This is the original sql:

```
SELECT st.scope_type,
       COALESCE(Sum(0 + 1), 0)
FROM   scope_inventory_view i
       INNER JOIN security y
               ON y.security_id = i.update_user
       INNER JOIN product_info vp
               ON vp.product_id = i.product_id
       INNER JOIN hl_vendorproduct hvp
               ON hvp.product_id = i.product_id
       INNER JOIN hl_scopetype st
               ON st.scope_type_id = i.scope_type_id
       INNER JOIN hl_itemstatus ist
               ON ist.item_status_id = COALESCE(i.item_status_id, 108)
       LEFT JOIN hl_owner o
              ON o.owner_id = i.owner_id
       LEFT JOIN hl_location l
              ON l.location_id = i.location_id
       LEFT JOIN hl_locationtype lt
              ON lt.location_type_id = l.location_type_id
       LEFT JOIN hl_sterilizerload sl
              ON sl.load_id = i.load_id
       LEFT JOIN hl_facility f
              ON f.facility_id = l.facility_id
       LEFT JOIN clientoption co
              ON co.parent_option_id = 271
                 AND ( co.facility_id = f.facility_id
                        OR co.facility_id IS NULL )
       LEFT JOIN clientoption clo
              ON clo.option_id = 271
                 AND ( clo.facility_id = f.facility_id
                        OR clo.facility_id IS NULL ),
       gl_client
WHERE  COALESCE(i.item_status_id, 108) <> 117
GROUP  BY st.scope_type WITH rollup
```

is there a better way to write this so that status 117 items are filtered out UNLESS the user requests them? If they do the sql query ends like so: (which gives no results)

```
WHERE  COALESCE(i.item_status_id, 108) <> 117
       AND ( ist.item_status_id IN( '117' ) )
GROUP  BY st.scope_type WITH rollup
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That query looks "wrong".Why do you `LEFT JOIN` to all of those tables when youdon't reference any of them? Why do you switch to a ANSI-89 `CROSS JOIN` for the table `gl_client`? Also `COALESCE(i.item_status_id, 108) <> 117` isn't SARGable; don't use functions on your columns in the `WHERE` or `ON` clauses. Have `NULL` values properly: `WHERE (i.item_status_id <> 117 OR i.item_status_id IS NULL)`. `COALESCE(Sum(0 + 1), 0)`? When is `0 + 1` ever `NULL`?

Comment: I don't see how you can make a query that has a condition like `WHERE something = true AND something = false`.  If the user requests them, the query has to be changed on application side.  If you are showing it on a report, then add a special columns saying whether the items are active or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has a lot of tables and joins which are not used in the select or the where conditions. Maybe you've simplified it for the question? If not eliminate the redundant tables in the join.
For your question of including or excluding 117 I suggest that you add the following column in your `SELECT`, and the same expression in the `GROUP BY` .

```
CASE WHEN 117 THEN '117' ELSE 'others' END AS type_group
```

The end using will be presented with the 2 figures for each `scope_type` which can be added together whether in code or by the person using the data if they wish to include type 117.